# Is it possible that accuracy testing and the accuracy training are 1.00 in binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, overfitting, boosting

I am working to improve classification results with more ML algorithm. I get 100 percent accuracy in both test and training set.

I used GradientBoostingClassifier, XGboost , RandomForest and Xgboost with GridSearchCV

My daset shape is (222,70), for the 70 features i have 25 binary features and 44 continious features.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

My code for Xgboost with GridSearchCV looks like this :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import xgboost as xgb

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15,random_state=141)
steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
       ('XGB',xgb.XGBClassifier(objective= 'binary:logistic'))]
                                                          
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps) # define the pipeline object.

parameteres = {'XGB__learning_rate':[0.01,0.1, 0.25,0.5,0.7,0.8,1], 
               'XGB__n_estimators':[5,8,9,10,11,20,100],
               'XGB__max_depth':[1,2,3,5,8,10,20]}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5,verbose=True)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print ("score = %3.2f" %(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print (grid.best_params_)
```

The result looks like this :

```
score = 1.00
{'XGB__learning_rate': 0.01, 'XGB__max_depth': 1, 'XGB__n_estimators': 5}
```

And the result with GradientBoostingClassifier and RandomForest looks like this

```
GradientBoostingClassifier
****Results****
Accuracy test: 100.0000%
Accuracy trainning: 100.0000%
Log Loss: 9.992007221626415e-16
confusion matrix
matrix: [[18  0]
        [ 0 16]]

RandomForestClassifier
****Results****
Accuracy test: 100.0000%
Accuracy trainning: 100.0000%
Log Loss: 9.992007221626415e-16
confusion matrix
matrix: [[18  0]
        [ 0 16]]
```

How to interpret this result ?

It is possible that my classifiers are overfitting the training set ?

Comment: I don't program in R, so I can't help you with the code, but if you had an overfitting problem the accuracy wouldn't be 100% also in the test set. However, it's very unlikely that the accuracy is actually perfect in both sets...

Comment: Thank you.  The code is in Python. i think that there is a  problem with my dataset

Comment: If you have a depth of 1 and are getting perfect accuracy then you probably have significant leakage.  Looks like your target variable is probably in your X.

Comment: @Tylerr what you means by "depth of 1"  please  ?

Comment: @dhifallahothmen Looks like your gridsearch returned this as the optimal parameters: {'XGB__learning_rate': 0.01, 'XGB__max_depth': 1, 'XGB__n_estimators': 5} which is a very very simple model.  Your tree only makes one split each iteration (this is the depth) and I bet you could get that 100% accuracy with XGB_n_estimators set to 1 because you have something in your X matrix which is 100% correlated with your y and it most likely IS your y or some metric which is based on your y.  Basically, you have bad data leakage somewhere.

Comment: @Tylerr  Yes you are right. Indeed, I have the same result with XGB_n_estimators = 1. I  think too that there is a problem in my dataset . But how to deal with bad data leakage. ? 
which statistical study will allow me to identify the features that correlate with my target ?

Comment: How do you interpret any model result? It seems like you've found a model that does well on the training and the test data. But also, you only have 34 observations in your hold-out, so maybe that's cause for concern -- your estimates of performance may exhibit high variance.